# error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Gdi32.lib', while building code in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++

I changed the library path from project properties -> Linker -> Input but till it giving error
I installed Window SDK for VS 2012, but till it not working.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

LNK1181 occurs when the .lib or .obj files that are specified during linking, are not found in the current directory, any of the directories that are specified by the LIBPATH linker option, or any of the directories that are specified in the LIB environment variable.

For more information [visit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815645)

Comment: I given the path "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\gdi32.lib, in Additional linker dependencies....But till it is not working